# OpenLayers is not defined while accessing over the html and js

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, ext-js, eclipse

[image]

The above is my working directory, all html files are under WebContent folder and the problem is that when all the code is written in a single html file working fine.
If I split the OpenLayers code into 'js' files under 'js' folder. The files within 'js' folder couldn't refer OpenLayers library(OpenLayers.js).

**ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined**
So that var's not getting initialized.

```
{
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-321/resources/css/ext-all.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-321/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-321/ext-all.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocoding.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tbar.js"></script>
        <script src="ol-211/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script src="ol-211/firebug.js"></script>
}
```

working with localhost.
and calling init() method explicitly from Ext.onLoad() while I am calling with in the same page it works fine and there is no problem with map it is displaying

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "ext-321/resources/images/default/s.gif";
        // turn on validation errors beside the field globally
        Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';
        new Ext.Viewport({
        layout      :   'border',
        renderTo    :   Ext.getBody(),
        region  :   "center",
        //margins   :   '0 5 5 0',
        defaults:   {border:false},
        items       :   [{
            region  :   "center",
            layout  :   "fit",
            id      :   "center_region",
            /*//tbar    :   new Ext.Toolbar({//551
                            id: 'map-toolbar'
                        }),
            html    :   "<div id='map' style='height:100%;width:100%;'></div>"
            *///555//
            items   :[{
                xtype   :"tabpanel",
                id      :"tab_map_status",
                activeTab: 0,
                defaults    :   {border:false},
                items:[{
                            title   :   'Map',
                            id      :   'tab-map',
                            tbar    :   new Ext.Toolbar({
                                            id: 'map-toolbar',
                                            items: []
                                        }),
                            html    :   "<div id='map' style='height:100%;width:100%;'></div>" 
                        }]}]});init();});'
```

Please help me.

Comment: you need to provide your HTML and also explain how you're accessing your site, e.g. http://localhost/... or http://localhost/some/site/name/...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of your js-files. Load OpenLayers before the files within js-folder.

```
<script src="ol-211/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="ol-211/firebug.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocoding.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tbar.js"></script>
```